# Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php

Any idea why i might be getting this error when submitting to a DB?

Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/somebody/public_html/sendmessage.php on line 41

```
while($success == FALSE) { 
$rand = rand(100000, 999999); 

$q = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id = '$rand'"; 
$r = mysql_query($q, $link);

echo mysql_error();


if(mysql_num_rows($r)) { **THIS IS LINE 41** 
    continue; 
} else { 
    $success = TRUE; 
} 
}
```

Comment: What does the table look like?

Comment: Please post the schema of the table.

Answer (score 2):

Your table, whose name is stored in `$tablename`, does not have a column named `id`. This makes the query fail, and all following database functions will also fail.

Comment: // insert your data here with $rand as the id
$query = "INSERT into $tablename values ('$rand', '$youremail', '$name', '$receiveremail', '$message')";

Comment: This comment does not relate to my answer, and it does not contain the columns of the table.

Comment: The columns are rand, youremail, name, receiveremail and message. rand is to store a randonly generated id and is getting submitted to the database but nothing else is for some reason

Comment: If the column you care about is actually called `rand`, not `id`, then you have to refer to it that way.

Comment: Ok, then where is the column named "id"? It does not exist, and that's why you get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

I ran into this error too, I discovered I was calling a different table that doesn't have id attributes. So I suggest you check your table name

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look too nice there,

first make sure you HAVE a column "id" in that table at all.
and beware "id" is NOT "Id" nor "ID" nor "iD"!
After being absolutely sure you HAVE that column, and still getting an error, try it with
quatation marks:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM ". $tablename ." WHERE 'id'='". $rand."'";
```

Comment: ok im able to send the $rand to the database but the other 4 columns are receiving nothing, the variables are all the same 
here's the structure http://i50.tinypic.com/14jq3he.png can u see anything that needs changed?

Comment: You SELECT FROM database, so the database doesn't "receive" anything but said request, and it'll return the matching (if any) result as an array, since rand should be a unique key it'll return exactly ONE row but since I cannot tell from the picture if it is set as unique it might be that you'll receive more than one row, so you should act accordingly. $r does not contain values, but a pointer to your request use mysql_fetch_array($r) to get the values

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Thanks

while($success == FALSE) { 
    $rand = rand(100000, 999999);

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM ". $tablename ." WHERE id = '". $rand ."'"; 
$r = mysql_query($q, $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($r);

echo mysql_error();


if($num_rows > 0) { **THIS IS LINE 41** 
    continue; 
} else { 
    $success = TRUE; 
} 
}
```

Cheers!